# 301 Moved Permanently - new link to redirect page?

Tags: http, http-status-code-301, http-response-codes

I´m building a program to read the follwoing url:
http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/USDEUR:CUR

and the response I get is:

```
> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Server: Apache Location:
> https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/XAGUSD:CUR Content-Type: text/html;
> charset=iso-8859-1 Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Encoding: gzip
> Content-Length: 209 Cache-Control: max-age=60 Expires: Fri, 28 Oct
> 2016 20:13:45 GMT Date: Fri, 28 Oct 2016 20:12:45 GMT Connection:
> close Set-Cookie: MARKETS_AP=J09; path=/ Set-Cookie: SRV=JPX04; path=/
> Set-Cookie: ak_rg=Europe; expires=Fri, 04-Nov-2016 20:12:45 GMT;
> path=/ Set-Cookie: ak_co=ES; expires=Fri, 04-Nov-2016 20:12:45 GMT;
> path=/
```

the question is: Where is the new link to the redirect page?
thanks

Comment: There are better API to convert currency than scraping a website

Comment: Hi cricket_007... any API that you recommend? thx

Comment: Anything that's free. A quick Google search brought up at least 3. You just need an account and an API key. I have no specific  recommendations, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Location header, in your example https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/XAGUSD:CUR

(which seems a bit strange looking at the currency pairs)